# Выравнивание TextView относительно ImageView

Tags: android, android-textview, android-imageview

У меня есть ImageView и TextView.
ImageView и TextView вместе находятся в одном родителе - Relative Layout.
Мне надо сделать так, чтобы выравнивание TextView происходило не относительно родителя, а относительно ImageView.
Так сказать "привязать" TextView к ImageView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выставите атрибуты для `TextView`:

```
android:layout_alignRight="@id/img"
android:layout_alignLeft="@id/img"
```

Сам `img` должен идти в `xml` раньше (либо здесь значение нужно заменить на `"@+id/img"`, а там - на `"@id/img"`)

Программно это можно сделать как-то так:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, text.getId());
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, text.getId());        
img.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: Подскажете пожалуйста, как это сделать в Java Class, если ImageView и TextView добавляются динамически?

Comment: @Александр, добавил в ответ

Comment: вообще практика динамического создания `img+text` не очень хорошая. Не знаю, какая у вас идея, но как правило для таких объектов используется `RecyclerView`, обратите на него внимание.

Comment: Да, работает. Только есть один момент. Я могу перемещать ImageView влево. Но TextView вместе с ним не перемещается. Как сделать так, чтобы TextView в реальном времени выравнивался относительно ImageView?

Comment: Если у вас что-то типа drag&drop - лучше перетаскивать весь контейнер целиком. Если у вас img "прыгает" внутри контейнера, каждый раз после перемещения заново выставляйте lp. За красоту анимации в последнем случае я не ручаюсь, лучше двигать весь контейнер)